# Cannot install bootstrap with bower

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, npm, bower

I am trying to install bootstrap in my app directory on my Mac. I have tried tips from different topics trying to solve this problem but something is different with my problem it seems.

Below are the commands that i put in the command line and the errors that it spits out.

```css
Jains-iMac:conFusion thejains$ bower init
? name conFusion
? description Website for an awesome restaurant
? main file index.html
? what types of modules does this package expose? 
? keywords conFusion, Fusion Restaurant
? authors Mayank Jain
? license MIT
? homepage 
? set currently installed components as dependencies? Yes
? add commonly ignored files to ignore list? Yes
? would you like to mark this package as private which prevents it from being accidentally published to the registry? Yes

{
  name: 'conFusion',
  description: 'Website for an awesome restaurant',
  main: 'index.html',
  moduleType: [],
  keywords: [
    'conFusion',
    'Fusion',
    'Restaurant'
  ],
  authors: [
    'Mayank Jain'
  ],
  license: 'MIT',
  homepage: '',
  private: true,
  ignore: [
    '**/.*',
    'node_modules',
    'bower_components',
    'test',
    'tests'
  ]
}

? Looks good? Yes
Jains-iMac:conFusion thejains$ bower install bootstrap -S
bower bootstrap#*           not-cached git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#*
bower bootstrap#*              resolve git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#*
bower bootstrap#*              ECMDERR Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git", exit code of #69   Agreeing to the Xcode/iOS license requires admin privileges, please re-run as root via sudo.

Additional error details:
Agreeing to the Xcode/iOS license requires admin privileges, please re-run as root via sudo.
Jains-iMac:conFusion thejains$ bower install twitter
bower twitter#*             not-cached git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#*
bower twitter#*                resolve git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git#*
bower twitter#*                ECMDERR Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git", exit code of #69   Agreeing to the Xcode/iOS license requires admin privileges, please re-run as root via sudo.

Additional error details:
Agreeing to the Xcode/iOS license requires admin privileges, please re-run as root via sudo.
```

P.S. I have tried changing the permissions with sudo chown and also bower clean cache. they didn't work.

Comment: Does running `git ls-remote --tags --heads git://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git` on the commandline give you the same error?

Comment: That awesome. I ran your command and it said 
`You have not agreed to Xcode license agreements. please re-run as root via sudo`. I did that and then it showed me agreement to agree to. I did so and then ran `bower cache clean`. After that I tried to install bootstrap with bower again by `bower install bootstrap -S`.It worked. Thanks so much.

For understanding this problem, could you please explain what the problem was? Thanks a ton :)

Comment: Well, I'm not entirely sure as I don't have a Mac (besides my iPhone), but I'm guessing that your `git` is part of Xcode, which wanted you to accept a license, either on a first-run, or after an update. Glad it worked!